# Simple Censor Program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I made a function to censor a certain word from a piece of text. Is there anything I should fix or do more efficiently? What are some other approaches I could have taken to detecting words and censoring them?(This took me a lot of time to brainstorm)

Also, I would appreciate it if you told me how you brainstorm how to write a program.

```
def detect_word_start(text,word):
    count = 0
    text_count = 0
    for x in text:
        text_count+=1
        if x == word[count]:
            count+=1
            if count == len(word):
                return text_count - len(word) + 1
        else:
            count = 0

def censor(text,word):
    word_start = detect_word_start(text,word)
    censored_text = ''
    count = 0
    for x in text:
        count += 1
        if count >= word_start and count < word_start+len(word):
            censored_text += '*'
        else:
            censored_text += x
        print(censored_text)
```

Comment: You could have a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/function-to-censor-single-word-in-a-sentence) if you're searching for ideas :)

Comment: oh damn, I just realized I could make this program way simpler with .split()

Comment: That's cl***ic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Bugs

The `censor()` function prints its progress as a triangle of text, as `censored_text` lengthens one character at a time.  Did you accidentally indent the `print()` statement one level too far?  In any case, it would be better practice to `return` its output, so that the caller can choose to `print()` it instead (or do something else with it).

"Censoring" implies that all appearances of the `word` should be replaced.  However, your `censor()` function only replaces the first occurrence, since `count` is never reset to 0.

Your `detect_word_start(text, word)` function is basically [`text.index(word)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), with some differences:

- If the `word` is not found, it returns `None`, whereas `text.index(word)` would raise a `ValueError` exception.  Since the `censor()` function **doesn't handle the possibility that the `word` never appears in the `text`,** your code could crash.  (I would expect the `censor()` function to return the `text` unmodified, if there is nothing to redact.)
- It returns a **one-based index**, which is very unconventional in Python, where indexes start from 0.  (Your `censor()` function also counts characters starting from 1, so at least you are consistent.)
- It **misses some possible results** because it makes one pass through the `text`, and will not backtrack.  For example, `detect_word_start('coconut', 'con')` and `detect_word_start('nonoperational', 'nope')` both return `None`.

  That might be acceptable behaviour, if you are only searching for complete space-delimited words.  However, from the way the code was written, it appears that this behaviour was unintended.

### More expressive and efficient code

Counting loops are usually better written using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Python supports [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`…

Here is the same code, preserving your 1-based indexing convention and other censorship bugs:

```
def censor(text, word):
    word_start = detect_word_start(text, word)
    censored_text = ''
    for i, char in enumerate(text, 1):
        if word_start <= i < word_start + len(word):
            censored_text += '*'
        else:
            censored_text += x
    return censored_text
```

We can save a few lines using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).  (I know, it looks worse, but there's a reason that you'll see…)

```
def censor(text, word):
    word_start = detect_word_start(text, word)
    censored_text = ''
    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        censored_text += '*' if (word_start <= i < word_start + len(word)) else x
    return censored_text
```

There is an efficiency problem with your code.  Python strings are immutable.  Therefore, [building strings using `+=` concatenation is not optimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> Concatenating immutable sequences always results in a new object. This means that building up a sequence by repeated concatenation will have a quadratic runtime cost in the total sequence length.

A way to avoid that performance problem would be to construct the result using [`''.join(…)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) along with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
def censor(text, word):
    word_start = detect_word_start(text, word)
    return ''.join(
        '*' if word_start <= i < word_start + len(word) else x
        for i, char in enumerate(text)
    )
```

### Simple solution

There is a very simple solution, using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and the [`*` operation on a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, '*' * len(word))
```

Answer (score 13):

Let's start by removing print from the loop and add a return value

```
def censor(text,word):
    #[...]
        else:
            censored_text += x
    return censored_text
```

now we have a testable function. we add some tests

```
import unittest

class TestSome(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_not_found(self):
        self.assertEqual(censor("", "bar"), "")
        self.assertEqual(censor("f", "bar"), "f")
        self.assertEqual(censor("foo", "bar"), "foo")
        self.assertEqual(censor("fooo", "bar"), "fooo")

    def test_found(self):
        self.assertEqual(censor("bar", "bar"), "***")
        self.assertEqual(censor("bar!", "bar"), "***!")
        self.assertEqual(censor("cow bar", "bar"), "cow ***")

    def test_parts(self):
        self.assertEqual(censor("foobar", "bar"), "foobar")
        self.assertEqual(censor("bare", "bar"), "bare")

    def test_capital(self):
        self.assertEqual(censor("Bar", "bar"), "***")

    def test_multiple(self):
        self.assertEqual(censor("foo bar bar foo", "bar"), "foo *** *** foo")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running the tests show that the functions are not meeting my expectations.

- `detect_word_start()` does not return a value if nothing found
- you miss words at the beginning of a sentence becaue of capitalization
- you censor different words containing the character sequence
- you miss multiple appearences

Comment: Perhaps it would be worthwhile to explain/link to the concept of TDD? IE, that it might have been easier to create the tests before the implementation and code from there.

Comment: And then we run into the eternal question of "how much testing is enough?" Personally, I'd at least like to test that censoring `bar` will not change `ba`, `babar` or `barbar`, and that it will correctly censor `BAR`, `(bar)` and `bar@bar.foo`. Oh, and at least one test where the censored word is something other than `bar`!